# Sending jq via SSH

Tags: json, bash, ssh, syntax, jq

When I running jq command locally it works:

```
jq --arg ip "$IP" '.nodes|.app|.ip = $ip' nodes.json
```

Output:

> {
>     "nodes": 1,
>     "is_manager": true,
>     "ip": "127.0.0.1",
>     "cpus": 16,
>     "memory": 64
>   }

But I can't figure out how do I send it remotely via ssh, for example this command returns an error:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem user@"172.13.1.23" "jq --arg ip "127.0.0.1" '.nodes|.app|.ip = $ip' nodes.json"
```

Output:

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
>   .nodes|.app|.ip =
>   jq: 1 compile error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ip` is in double quotes, and so is expanded locally. You need to escape the dollar sign.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i key.pem user@"172.13.1.23" \
  "jq --arg ip "127.0.0.1" '.nodes|.app|.ip = \$ip' nodes.json"
```

Comment: What about this command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428131/sending-jq-with-argjson-via-ssh